# Importing package from target in OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi

I'm having problems importing a package in an OSGi bundle.

The package called `org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.xmlliteral` is included in the jar file `org.semanticweb.HermiT.jar`. This jar is included in my target definition and selected in my run configuration. My target recognizes it as an OSGi bundle, so that shouldn't be the problem. When I try to import the package in my own bundle I get an error saying no bundle exports the package. Anyone who knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try adding it to `Import-Package` header of `Manifest`? Did you find that package there?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but he doesn't seem to find the package there..

Comment: Is the bundle org.semanticweb.HermiT in active state? You should check it via a console and if not why not. Also check if that bundle exports the package with the necessary version.

Comment: Would be nice if you could define what exact error you get and what your setup is. I guess you use Eclipse PDE?

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse PDE. I have looked inside the jar and I saw that in the included MANIFEST.MF there are no exported packages. But it seems pretty impossible to change that. Are there any ways to fix this? The error is get is 'No available bundle exports the package 'org.semanticweb.HermiT.datatypes.xmlliteral'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the standard download for "org.semanticweb.HermiT.jar", it has no Export-Package. Therefore none of the packages within the JAR are usable by other OSGI components.

UPDATE:

The pax-url wrap plugin can help you wrap your non-osgi JAR into an osgi bundle and add arbitrary MANIFEST lines.

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol

There may also be a reason they don't include Export-Package. You may want to ask the creator(s) directly to make sure you aren't looking for trouble.

You can also just update the JAR you have, then always use that when deploying. There are a TON of options actually.

You can also see how this project does it:

http://iks-project.googlecode.com/svn-history/r794/sandbox/kres/trunk/eu.iksproject.kres.shared/dependency/hermit124/pom.xml

They create a pom.xml and provide their OWN manifest entries using the maven bundle plugin.

Comment: Ok, that was what I suspected yet. Is there a way to change this? I already tried to simply change the MANIFEST.MF and add the exported package. But it seems pretty hard to make it a jar again..

Comment: You basically have to 'wrap' the jar as a valid osgi bundle. EDIT: oops, hit enter. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actually a jar file is just a ZIP file, so making it a jar again is easy. You might make the hash not match but I'm not 100% sure that is an issue here.

Comment: I have tried to uncompress the jar file, change the MANIFEST and put it in a jar archive again, but this didn't work. It wasn't recognized as a OSGi jar anymore. I solved it in a different way, I simply included the jar in my bundle as referenced library. This is not how it should be done in OSGi I suppose, but it works and I don't need the jar in my other bundles, so I don't have to include it twice somewhere..